# Pandas - Dataframe: Sort same values in same column , and if in Row value does not exist put NaN (or 0)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting, group-by, alignment

I built a dataframe which already grouped from a dataset all the same Frequencies of different Channels together. Now in each row I have first my frequency and then the Channels in which it occurs.
But I want that in Column "Channel 1" I just cann see the "1"s and not the other numbers. If there is no "1" for that Frequency I just want no  value in this cell. I tried around with sort , align,.. but I am always failing:
[What i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4SVj.png)

So that at the end i get something like this... I am just showing it with excel here, but I would like to get it from python:
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otCNj.png)

thank you!

Comment: Please post your code and add your result and expected result as text instead of images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numy as np  

for i in df.columns:
    df[i] = np.where(float(df[i].name.split(' ')[1]) == df[i],
                     df[i], np.nan)
```